# There is no cubedata.h and contrib directory in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, image-recognition

I has 128-dimensional vectors of float (face recognition issue). To store these vectors I use datatype cube in Postgresql.
This type has limit by default - 100 dim.

In the psql (PostgreSQL) 10.5 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) this limit don't work: I can store my vector without any problems.
But yeasterday one of my machine was updated to PostgreSQL 10.6 and now I receive an error when try to add new cube-vector into my database. Error about too long vector.

To resolve this problem I have to change this limit in the file **cubedata.h** which is in **contrib** directory. But I have no this file and such directory at all!

I try install

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

but, I get the message about the newest postgresql-contrib version is already installed.

After I tried to manually download cubedata.h file into the directory of Postgresql (/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/), but it doesn't help.

My be someone encountered with such problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu  18.04.1 **cubedata.h** included in the `postgres-server-dev-10` package from the PostgreSQL [official repository](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). But prebuilt `cube.so` included in the `postgresql-10` package with default limit.

To increase the limit you should recompile `cube.so` from source. Below the example of code for the Ubuntu.

Add repository:

```sh
PG_VER=10.6
source /etc/os-release
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ ${VERSION_CODENAME}-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-${PG_VER%.*}
```

Compile `cube` extension from source:

```sh
PG_VER=10.6
sudo apt-get install -y unzip gcc make zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev postgresql-server-dev-${PG_VER%.*} bison flex
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v${PG_VER}/postgresql-${PG_VER}.tar.bz2 --quiet -O postgresql.tar.bz2
tar xvf postgresql.tar.bz2
cd postgresql-${PG_VER}
./configure
cd contrib/cube
sed -i 's/#define CUBE_MAX_DIM (100)/#define CUBE_MAX_DIM (128)/' cubedata.h
make USE_PGXS=1
sudo make USE_PGXS=1 install
```

Check result after restart server:

```sh
sudo -u postgres psql dbname -c 'CREATE EXTENSION cube'
sudo -u postgres psql dbname -c 'SELECT cube_dim(cube(array(select generate_series(1, 128)))) as dim'
```